# i need to create python script to lock computer in idle time and record login in a file with date and time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a script by python to lock the user's screen when they are not active on their computers (idle time) and when they are login again it records login time and date in a file.
the below code lock screen only.

> ```
> import ctypes
> ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
> ```

I'm a new to programming
anyone can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there anyway to lock computer in idle time and record login in a file with date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528307/is-there-anyway-to-lock-computer-in-idle-time-and-record-login-in-a-file-with-da)

Comment: Reposting your own question after it was closed is not appropriate. Instead you should edit the previous question. Then it will go into a queue to be reviewed for re-opening.